# Workflow With Attachment

Tags: workflow, email, attachments, notifications

I'm new to Sharepoint and I'm trying to create a Workflow that every document uploaded to a list, it sends an e-mail to a person with the attachment, but 2 thing are happening with my Worflow.

1: When a new document is created, the creator receives an e-mail that the Workflow was initiated (I don't want the uploader to be notified)

2: When the persons receives the e-mail from Sharepoint, it doesn't show the attachment, just "True".

Can anybody help with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send attachments out of the box, you'd have to do some custom code on the back end or use a third party solution. You can include a link to the content, though.

There is a method described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/212023/41066) by Nullldata that walks you through which field values to use.

Comment: And about the notifications? I deleted the Workflow and uploaders are still geting notifications that they started the Workflow, but it was already deleted.

Comment: You may have to cancel any active workflows if you want to stop them (go to the site or list you had the workflow attached to and go to workflows and end them).

Comment: Already did it. I don't have any Workflows but it still sending notifications.

Comment: Are the email notifications that are being sent out task notifications or emails that were generated in the workflow?

Comment: There are "Previous" Workflow versions that can still run - even if the workflow has been superseded. You may have to terminate and / or delete the previous versions of the workflow.

Cheers for the shout out @Graham :)