# Link in email to automatically open/download attachments?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, custom-list

I have a SharePoint list that automatically sends an email through a work flow once a list item is submitted.

Is there a way to have a link provided in the email that will download the contents attached to a list item?

Right now I have a link in the email that sends users to the list item itself, where they then need to click on the attachments to view them, and click on another button to download the attachments.

I'd like to save clicks if possible since I've been getting a decent amount of feedback regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone curious in how to get a download link for attachments, the second answer at  [this URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159183/get-url-of-list-item-attachment-from-sharepoint-designer-2010?rq=1) did the trick for me. I should mention, since you're basically building the attachment URL, it'll only work for one file or one zipped file. If you attach multiple files, it'll only download the first attached file. I'm working to see if there is an attachment validation method I can use to force .zip files only.